# How is the user authentication with Google accounts working inside the GAE technically

Tags: google-app-engine

Applications that run inside the Google App Engine can use Google Accounts for user authentication. I already used this feature and it works great. I just want to know how this is working. Is there a HTTP cookie created? How can an application inside the GAE see that a user is logged in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AppEngine SDK takes care of the details for you, but essentially it generates the equivalent of an OAuth request to the Google Account service. All interactions with the login process go through the Google Account service (and thus the cookies it uses for session tracking are not available to the individual app).